# Creating multiple rooms for various users in a multiplayer game node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have created a card game (Indian Poker) for multiplayer in Nodejs and angular js. The game is working perfectly fine with 5 players over one table. We want it for more players and more tables. I believe I am only able to run this game over a single socket. I am new to node.js hence would like a guide for multiple sockets. I have tried almost everything on google but unable to proceed with it. Below I am attaching io.js and tabledeck.js. I don't know what to change and where to change. I am using mongo db as database.

io.js
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/938b0bc7848b11f542a60d5686813fc2

tabledeck.js
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0d205a38312b9eba0b9476c3005f8151

Please look into it and provide a solution to convert into multiple rooms.

Comment: can't you just use an object to store each room ? like `var mainObj =  {room1: {user1: socket, ... }, room2: {...} ... }`

Comment: Please elaborate or provide a reference link. Also there has to be as many as 4000 rooms at a point of time, rooms will have different boot value and pot limit.

Comment: I don't see how i can elaborate, this is a simple structure that allows you to keep rooms, if you are trying to keep a large amount of rooms, you should try to split them into diffrent object, such as room 1 to 100 , 101 to 200, etc.

Comment: but this is an algorithm, you will have to develop yourself.

Comment: Better use socket.io